# php soapClient - does not generate any XML, __getFunctions() is empty - no errors

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm running php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
with
php-soap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
php-xml-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.x86_64

I'm trying to  access the affilinet webservice (I've tried other webservices as well, with the same result)

$soap_client->__getFunctions() returns nothing
The SOAP-request sent is only the 3 values Username, Password, WebServiceType concatenated - no XML structure around it.

```
$soap_client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('trace'=>true, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

var_dump($soap_client->__getFunctions());

$params->Username = $this->id;
$params->Password = $this->password;
$params->WebServiceType = "Product";

try {
$result = $soap_client->Logon($params);
                              //new SoapParam($this->id,"Username"),
                              //new SoapParam($this->password,"Password"),
                              //new SoapParam("Product","WebServiceType"));
} catch(Exception $ex) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while writing down the question I figured it out:

installing the 32bit package of libxml2 (libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.i686) solved the problem.